# Why does the build fail with org.kie#kie-spring;6.1.0.Final on Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, sbt, playframework-2.2

I use Play 2.2.3 with Java and `sbt.version=0.13.5`.

When I run `play clean compile` I can see:

```
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 27, 2014 3:12:26 PM
```

but when I run `sbt compile stage` or `deploy` or a mere `sbt clean compile` on Heroku, this message is generated:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/imadeddine/git/maretraitev3/play/project
[info] Set current project to play (in build file:/home/imadeddine/git/maretraitev3/play/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 31, 2014 8:56:52 AM
[info] Updating {file:/home/imadeddine/git/maretraitev3/play/}play...
[info] Resolving org.jboss.dashboard-builder#dashboard-builder-bom;6.1.0.Final ...
[warn] io problem while parsing ivy file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/kie-parent-with-dependencies/6.1.0.Final/kie-parent-with-dependencies-6.1.0.Final.pom: Impossible to import module for file:/home/imadeddine/.ivy2/cache/org.kie/kie-parent-with-dependencies/ivy-6.1.0.Final.xml.original. Import=org.jboss.dashboard-builder#dashboard-builder-bom;6.1.0.Final

......

[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.kie#kie-spring;6.1.0.Final: not found::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.kie#kie-spring;6.1.0.Final: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1144)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1142)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1165)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1163)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1167)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1162)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1170)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1135)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1113)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.kie#kie-spring;6.1.0.Final: not found
[error] Total time: 59 s, completed Aug 31, 2014 8:57:52 AM
```

Why? How to fix this?

Comment: `play` is pretty much `sbt` command-wise so I'm surprised to have read your issues. Can you include the entire error stack trace up to the error UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES? I'm pretty sure it's because the repositories are not available from Heroku.

Comment: thank-you for your response ... the issue updated...

Answer (score 3):

According to the error message, it appears there's an issue with parsing the pom - http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/kie-parent-with-dependencies/6.1.0.Final/kie-parent-with-dependencies-6.1.0.Final.pom, esp. the part

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.dashboard-builder</groupId>
  <artifactId>dashboard-builder-bom</artifactId>
  <type>pom</type>
  <version>${dashboard-builder.version}</version>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

There are few cases already reported where parsing more complex poms with advanced features of Maven employed have caused failures in sbt (citation needed).

It appears that the issue is due to a missing resolver for the dependency. Add the following to `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "jboss-releases" at "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases"
```